# Why Angular application built with Cordova does not see NFC?

Tags: angular, cordova

Can you tell me why Angular application built with Cordova does not see NFC (Android)?

The phonegap-nfc 1.2.0 "NFC" plugin is installed in Cordova (v11.1.0)

component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

const Nfc = (window as any).nfc;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {
  isNfcSupported: boolean;
  tagData: string | undefined;
  scanError: string | undefined;

  constructor() {
    this.isNfcSupported = !!Nfc;
  }

  scanNfc() {
    if (this.isNfcSupported) {
      Nfc.addTagDiscoveredListener(
          (tag: any) => this.tagData = this.parseTagData(tag),
          (error: string | undefined) => this.scanError = error
      );
    }
  }

  private parseTagData(tag: any): string {
    return JSON.stringify(tag);
  }
}
```

component.html

```
<div *ngIf="isNfcSupported">
  <button (click)="scanNfc()">Scan NFC</button>
  <p *ngIf="tagData">Tag data: {{ tagData }}</p>
  <p *ngIf="scanError">Error: {{ scanError }}</p>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!isNfcSupported">
  NFC not supported on this device
</div>
```

I make a build, install it on the Android phone, and see the message "NFC not supported on this device", although the phone has NFC.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to wait for the asynchronous platform to be ready before setting your variable `this.isNfcSupported = !!Nfc;`

When the constructor is running, the device platform might not be ready and therefore window.nfc will not be there yet.

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-device/index.html

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    // here the device is ready and the plugin Nfc is available
}
```

With Ionic https://ionicframework.com/docs/angular/platform

```
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    this.isNfcSupported = !!Nfc;
});
```

In your plugin documentation you have a code example and they are using onDeviceReady here https://github.com/chariotsolutions/phonegap-nfc#tag-technology-functions-1

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work either:
`ngOnInit() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
  }

  onDeviceReady() {
    this.isNfcSupported = !!Nfc;
  }`

Comment: is deviceready triggerring at least ?